# Правильная структура программы. Избавление от глобальной переменной

Tags: c++

Проблема следующая. Я правлю баг, суть которого в невозможности завершения программы. Т.е. управление командной строке не возвращается.

Я взял пример кода от [сюда](https://github.com/Pelagicore/common-api-tools/blob/master/CommonAPI-Examples/E01HelloWorld/src/E01HelloWorldClient.cpp) (мы используем этот фрэймворк)
Код изменил, чтобы продемонстрировать свой случай:

```
#include <CommonAPI/CommonAPI.hpp>
#include <v0/commonapi/examples/E01HelloWorldProxy.hpp>

using namespace v0::commonapi::examples;

// глобальная переменная из-за которой не происходит правильного завершения
static std::shared_ptr<E01HelloWorldProxy<>> myProxy;

void helpFunction(){

    const std::string name = "World";
    CommonAPI::CallStatus callStatus;
    std::string returnMessage;

    CommonAPI::CallInfo info(1000);
    info.sender_ = 1234;

    while (true) {
        myProxy->sayHello(name, callStatus, returnMessage, &info);
        if (callStatus != CommonAPI::CallStatus::SUCCESS) {
            std::cerr << "Remote call failed!\n";
            return -1;
        }
        info.timeout_ = info.timeout_ + 1000;

        std::cout << "Got message: '" << returnMessage << "'\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main() {
    CommonAPI::Runtime::setProperty("LogContext", "E01C");
    CommonAPI::Runtime::setProperty("LibraryBase", "E01HelloWorld");

    std::shared_ptr < CommonAPI::Runtime > runtime = CommonAPI::Runtime::get();

    std::string domain = "local";
    std::string instance = "commonapi.examples.HelloWorld";
    std::string connection = "client-sample";

    myProxy = runtime->buildProxy<E01HelloWorldProxy>(domain, instance, connection);

    std::cout << "Checking availability!" << std::endl;
    while (!myProxy->isAvailable())
        usleep(10);
    std::cout << "Available..." << std::endl;

    if (conditon)
        helpFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в переменной `myProxy`. Она, как я понял, запускает thread при вызове метода `buildProxy`. Из-за того, что переменная глобальная, поток не убивается правильно.  Даже если завершится `main()`, программа не остановится.

Дополнительную проблему создает то, что в программе содержится структура с методом, который содержит `myProxy`.

```
struct Name {
   void metod() {
      myProxy->sayHello(name, callStatus, returnMessage, &info);
   }
}
```

Так что довольно сложно избавиться от это глобальной переменной без существенных переделок.

Решение я нашел пока только одно - сделать ее локальной. Тогда все работает нормально.

```
...
// заменил на указатель на shared_ptr
static std::shared_ptr<E01HelloWorldProxy<>> * myProxy;

void helpFunction(){
    ...
   while (true) {
     (*myProxy)->sayHello(name, callStatus, returnMessage, &info);
...
}

int main() {
...
   std::shared_ptr<E01HelloWorldProxy<>> local = 
             runtime->buildProxy<E01HelloWorldProxy>(domain, instance, connection);
   myProxy = &local;
...
}
```

Но решение получилось не очень красивое. Подскажите, как это сделать правильнее? 
Также мне желательно оставить `void helpFunction()` иначе придется много переделывать.

Comment: Добавьте параметр в `helpFunction`. Непонятно, что тут переделывать, она ведь только один раз вызывается.

Comment: "Из-за того, что переменная глобальная, поток не убивается правильно. Даже если завершится main(), программа не остановится." - нет, не так. При завершении main все потоки завершаются. Какие-то переменные вообще к делу не относятся. Если программа у вас не завершается, значит главный поток по-прежнему активен, это единственная причина.

Comment: @freim,  этот комментарий лучше было бы оформлять как ответ

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, да, вы правы, так и сделал.

Answer (score 1):

"Из-за того, что переменная глобальная, поток не убивается правильно. Даже если завершится main(), программа не остановится."

- Нет, не так. При завершении main все потоки завершаются. Какие-то переменные вообще к делу не относятся. Если программа у вас не завершается, значит главный поток по-прежнему активен, это единственная причина.

"Решение я нашел пока только одно - сделать ее локальной. Тогда все работает нормально. ... Но решение получилось не очень красивое. Подскажите, как это сделать правильнее?"

- Уж точно не очень красивое. :) А правильнее было бы разобраться из-за чего у вас подвисает и не завершается главный поток. Принудительно его можно завершить, например, функцией abort или terminate, но лучше все-таки понять что происходит, и нет ли там еще каких нежелательных эффектов. Сделайте трассировку выполнения в текстовый лог файл, очень полезная вещь для отладки многопоточных программ. Отладчик тут не всегда помогает, а лог выполнения хорошо показывает как взаимодействуют потоки.

Comment: только вы написали лишнее

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan - насчет трассировки? Ну, это то, что я всегда делаю в подобных ситуациях, обычно помогает. Может кто-нибудь посоветует что-нибудь поумнее.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю  что вам сказать., кроме того, что  те, кто минусует, вообше то должны  сами пояснить  причину.  Лично мне понравилась больше первая половина ответа...

Comment: Я делал лог. Пробовал  `std::atexit( handler )`. В "void handler()" делал вызов лога. Этот лог вышел. Делал в терминале htop. У процесса было четыре потока. 3 убилось, один продолжил висеть.

Comment: Согласен, что надо разобраться, что происходит под капотом фреймворка. Но там все довольно мудрено.

Comment: "У процесса было четыре потока. 3 убилось, один продолжил висеть." - значит, висел главный поток. Тут просто нет других вариантов, потому что при завершении главного потока завершается весь процесс. При необходимости - с принудительным завершением активных потоков. Для отладки есть еще хороший (по отзывам) инструмент - Intel Parallel Inspector. Сам я его, правда, не пробовал, так ничего о нем не скажу.